# zabbix monitor custom script value

Tags: linux, bash, zabbix

I tried to configure zabbix to monitor a value from my script,

But zabbix return an error:

```
Received value [200true] is not suitable for value type [Numeric (unsigned)] and data type [Decimal]
```

script:

```
status=$(curl -I https://example.com/health_check.jsp 2> /dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2);
if [ $status = "200" ]; then
    exit 0
else
    echo 1
fi
```

Zabbix configuration:

```
key - system.run[/zabbix_scripts/myscript.sh]
key type of information - numeric (unsigned)
key data type - decimal
trigger - {sso:system.run[/zabbix_scripts/myscript.sh].last()}=1
```

I did it before, but somehow this script not work with zabbix.

Please help,
Thanks!

Comment: What does this return on the problematic system? `curl -I https://example.com/health_check.jsp 2> /dev/null | head -n 1` - also, you are mixing `echo` and `exit`. While you probably meant `echo`, in this case it would be simpler to output the HTTP response code only.

Answer (score 1):

Although the error message is strange ("`Received value [200true]`" makes it look like the script outputs something strange, even though it really shouldn't), I see a problem in the usage of `exit 0`.

Zabbix does not evaluate exit codes of external scripts/binaries, it only reads the standard output.
Change it to `echo 0` to make the script print the value to stdout, thus making it visible for zabbix, e.g.:

```
status=$(curl -I https://example.com/health_check.jsp 2> /dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
if [[ $status = "200" ]]; then
    echo 0
else
    echo 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

While it would be interesting to find out why you get such a broken output, I'd suggest changing your whole script to this :

```
curl -s -I -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" https://example.com/health_check.jsp
```

Note that it will output the HTTP response code only, thus your trigger would have to be modified to check for the value not being 200 - `#200` for Zabbix 2.2 and earlier, `<>200` for 2.4 and later.

Answer (score 0):

The output values sent by this script to server has datatype conflicts.

You need to change the script as below, `echo 0` or `echo 1`, insted of `exit 0`.

If the status is 200, the output will be 0, if it is 1, you can trigger an alert.

```
status=$(curl -I https://example.com/health_check.jsp 2> /dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2);
if [ $status = "200" ]; then
    echo 0
else
    echo 1
fi
```